# Print filename and execute a command on each result of find

Tags: find

I am trying to apply two command (`echo` and `haml --check`) to result of my `find`.

```
haml --check `find . -name "*.haml"`
# return Syntax error on line 2: Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.
# but I don't know which file

echo `find . -name "*.haml"`
# returns list of files (space separated)
```

Ideally I want to print the file name and then output of `haml --check` of that file in `stdout`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also a way without xargs:

```
find . -name "*.haml" -ls -exec haml --check {} \;
```

to print out only file name with path:

```
find . -name "*.haml" -print -exec haml --check {} \;
```

Comment: I don't want to print file permissions and owner name. Just the path

Comment: That's not a problem. New variant is in the answer.

Comment: Best answer, but a bit confusing for those who expect a way to execute two distinct commands as the question title says. I'll propose an edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.haml" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 --no-run-if-empty haml --check
```

runs haml on each file found by `find`

If `haml` can take multiple files in one invocation, you can leave out the `-n 1`

Comment: Thanks! It is now iterating through files. I want to print the file name (argument that we are passing to `haml --check`) before executing `haml --check` too.

Comment: if you add `-v` to xargs as well, then it will print the command (`haml --check filename.haml` before execution. Is that ok or do you really need to have only the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portable and efficient way to execute multiple commands with find without using the GNU specific "-print0" and "xargs -0" tricks :

```
find . -name "*.haml" -exec sh -c 'for i; do echo $i;ls -l $i;haml --check $i; done' sh {} +
```